# How do filter user input (month) to be use in the analysis? (Python only)

Tags: python, pandas

Good day to all! In my analysis, I can set my df for analysis base on the month as below:

```
# Date range: April 2018
df = df[(df['a_date'] > '2018-04-01') & (df['a_date'] < '2018-05-01')]
```

Now I would like to ask user to choose which month to be the input for the analysis and I done the prompt user part as below:

```
MonthAnalysis = int(input("Enter which Month to analyse:"))

if MonthAnalysis <= 0 or MonthAnalysis > 12:
    print("Invalid, Choose again")
else:
    print(MonthAnalysis)
```

Now I not so sure how to use the user input to create the df for further analysis. Hope can get any advice for this. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it that only uses one comparison operation. If 'date' is not a datetime, cast it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd    
df['a_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then use the pandas `datetime` accessor (`.dt`):

```
df=df[((df['a_date'].dt.month==5) & (df['a_date'].dt.year==2018))]
```

Comment: @ ags29, that another to do it, yes, 'date' is not a datetime, maybe can change to 'a_date' then it will not be confusing, sorry for that.
So was wonder, since the dt.month==5, so the option prompt to user need to be change? and for your information, the initial function import as below:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need to change the user input as you are asking for months in any case (just replace '5' in the example above with the user input month). Also has the advantage that it works for all years, not just 2018

Comment: @ ags29, ohh, sorry ags29 if the raw data have year 2017 & 2018 data, then all the 5 will choose for this 2 year, also right? ohh no, i forget about this requirement too :( I might need to specify the year as well.

Comment: changed to reflect your requirement

Comment: @ ags29 Thank you for your editing. The one u propose is the backend that i can change myself, in order for user to input the month and year, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got your question right.

The most straightforward way would be holding a hard-coded list that matches the months to the string format you need for querying your DataFrame. So,

```
months = [('2018-01-01','2018-02-01'),('2018-02-01','2018-03-01'), ...]
```

Then you can use this list

```
else:
    df = df[(df['date'] > months[monthsAnalysis-1][0]) 
    & (df['date'] < months[monthsAnalysis-1][1])]
```

Comment: Thanks gokhansim for your speedy reply! The answer you give is straightforward to use. But would like to know what if the month selection can be more user friendly? For example, key in 4 will choose the date range of April only? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @Tyson You can perhaps prompt two arguments to denote the interval? If only one input is given,  then it's just a specific month. If two inputs are given, take the interval of the months instead.

Comment: @ gokhansim will it be possible only use one input to do it instead of the interval of the months?

Comment: You are the developer, so it's your decision to make :) If you think querying a single month is needed, then it should be possible. If you want to include an interval of months, it's possible too. If you have a UI component, you can let the user select the interval beginnings and ends from a dropdown list, or display a calendar to let the user pick. Using command line, you can still let the user give an input and force a strict format to this input, to query exact dates.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply again! I'm still new in this area, so not sure which one is the best. And finally this will compile with Pyinstaller to make a window program so it will be good as user friendly as possible. Thank you! :)

Comment: Try different options, put yourself in the shoes of the user. See which one you like better.

Comment: @ gokhansim Thanks for your advice! Will try to explore it more! But now i follow the code you given, it seem working, will try more on it again! Thanks again! :)